# Conditional Probability and Independency

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I assume to have two random variables $X,Y$ with pdfs $p_x,p_Y$, respectively. Unfortunately, I don't have much background knowledge on probability theory. I am wondering whether assuming $p(x | y)$ is identical for all $y \in Y$ automatically implies that $X$ and $Y$ are (stochastically) independent?

My feeling is that this is not automatically fulfilled. It is clear to me that the implication for the other direction (independency implies the same conditional density) is satisfied. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your meaning of "$p(x|y)$ is identical for all $y \in Y$." While I think you mean "for all $y \in S_Y$" (where $S_Y$ is the support) rather than "for all $y \in Y$," I still do not know what you mean by "identical." I would use PDF notation $f_X(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f_Y(y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. The conditional PDF can be $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Michael . You are totally right, I actually meant $y \in S_Y$. In the PDF notation by "identical" I mean that $f_{X|Y}(\cdot | y)$ follows the same distribution for all $y\in S_Y$ (which I think should be the same as assuming that $f_{X|Y}(x | y)$ takes the same value for all $x\in S_X, y\in S_Y$, right?)

Comment: So your function $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ depends only on $x\in\mathbb{R}$, meaning there is some function $g$ such that $g(x)=f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}, y\in S_Y$. Then it indeed holds that $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=f_X(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}, y \in S_Y$ because for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $$f_X(x)=\int_{y\in S_Y}f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y)dy=g(x)\underbrace{\int_{y \in S_Y}f_Y(y)dy}_{1}=g(x)$$

Comment: This totally makes sense to me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just duplicates my comment as an answer: If the conditional PDF $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ only depends on $x$, then there is a function $g$ such that
$$ f_{X|Y}(x|y)=g(x) \quad\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall y \in S_Y$$
where $S_Y$ is the support of the PDF of $Y$. Then for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{align}
f_X(x) &= \int_{y\in S_Y}f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y)dy \\
&=\int_{y\in S_Y} g(x)f_Y(y)dy\\
&=g(x)\int_{y\in S_Y}f_Y(y)dy\\
&=g(x)
\end{align}
and so
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=f_X(x) \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, y \in S_Y$$
which implies independence.

---

Note that random variables $X, Y$ are defined to be independent if $$P[X\leq x, Y\leq y] = P[X\leq x]P[Y\leq y] \quad x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$
although if a joint PDF exists and factors into a product of marginal PDFs, so $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, this is a sufficient condition for independence.